# What's a "Minister for Brexit"?

Tags: united-kingdom, brexit

[David Jones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Jones_(Clwyd_West_MP)) is described as formerly such "Minister for Brexit". But how is this job description related to the position of [Brexit Secretary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_of_State_for_Exiting_the_European_Union) which was (only) held by David Davis and is now held by Dominic Raab?

Answer (score 5):

"Minister for Brexit" is a more general description of high-level positions in the [Department for Exiting the European Union (DExEU)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Department_for_Exiting_the_European_Union). The Department is overseen by the Brexit Secretary (currently Raab), who himself counts as a "Minister for Brexit" (assuming Wikipedia is correct on this.)

There are two other positions that also count as a "Minister for Brexit":

- Minister of State for Exiting the European Union (currently held by Rt Hon. Lord Callanan)
- Parliamentary Under-Secretary of State for Exiting the European Union; with three MPs serving in this role currently.

More generally, a [Minister of State](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minister_of_State) is a more junior position in the British government, usually reporting to a Secretary.